# Trying to clone a repository in git, getting a error

Tags: git, windows-7, corruption, git-clone

I have two boxes, one is my local machine and the other is my dev server. Right now I'm testing [this method of deploying apps](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2009/11/23/deploying-a-web-application-with-git-and-ftp) using Git

I setup my local repository, added the files then committed. I am on Windows 7 & my server is Windows Server 2008.

The server is mapped as the W:\ Drive with my 'bare' repository and   my target 'mock' production folder as child folders. 
-- I can get to each just fine, no connection problems.

Here's what I did to setup everything:

1. Local dir git remote add origin w:\gitCentral
2. Local dir git push origin master
3. Type C:, then type CD testDeployment
4. Now I'm in my test folder.

   A. I do git clone w:/gitCentral

> `Cloning into gitCentral... done.`
>   `error: refs/remotes/origin/master does`
>   `not point to a valid object! error:`
>   `Trying to write ref refs/heads/master`
>   `with nonexistant object 559e2165845`
>   `06e14ebef1121059e9461a86dd4f8 fatal:`
>   `Cannot update the ref 'HEAD'.`

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but might I recommend adding the maximum amount of tags possible, as more people will see your question. try the tags git, error, repository, clone and maybe deploy. More tags will get more views, and a higher chance of actual answers! Good luck:)

Comment: @Joshua: Please encourage people to add all relevant tags. The wording "maximum possible" could lead to tag misuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do the following (starting from your local folder, considering it is a git repo and has commits in current HEAD):

```
git remote add origin w:/gitCentral
git fetch origin
git push origin master
cd C:/testDeployment
git clone w:/gitCentral
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening, I think, for one of two reasons:

Git wants forward slashes, not backward.
Git doesn't like spaces - use quotes.

So, if your remote is "w:\Repositories\My App" Git would like to see that as "'w:/Repositories/My App'".

That's my hunch.