# error: Trying to write ref HEAD with nonexistant object

Tags: git

I'm trying to clone a repo but can't. Here's what I get:

```
username@dev:~$ sudo git clone username@localhost:reponame reponame
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/username/reponame/.git/
username@localhost's password:
remote: Counting objects: 1017, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (425/425), done.
remote: Total 1017 (delta 490), reused 967 (delta 467)
Receiving objects: 100% (1017/1017), 18.44 MiB | 26.02 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (490/490), done.
error: Trying to write ref HEAD with nonexistant object 650847310778421960977df632ede735af9e9b86
fatal: Cannot update the ref 'HEAD'.
```

[Trying to clone a repository in git, getting a error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6588569/569976) has a few recommendations but I'm not trying to clone to an existent folder - I'm trying to clone to a new folder and obviously I'm not going to be able to add a remote to something that isn't even a git repo.

If I do it with a different username it works just fine. Just not this newly created user.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you in fact have a Git repo hosted on `localhost`, and is `localhost` properly serving requests for it?

Comment: Given that it works with `git clone username2@localhost:reponame reponame` I'm going to have to assume that it is. I don't know how else I'd check though :(

Comment: It sounds as though somehow HEAD is pointing at a non-existent object. Do you have any other branches? what happens if you do `git clone -b BRANCH username@localhost:reponame reponame` ?

Comment: @llion - that worked! Per `git branch` I only have one branch - `master`. How do I fix this so I don't need to specify a branch when cloning?

Comment: @Ilion Please put your comment below to make it an answer so op can mark it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though somehow HEAD is pointing at a non-existent object. Do you have any other branches? what happens if you do

```
git clone -b BRANCH username@localhost:reponame reponame
```